# R: Write data to a particular column in csv file

Tags: r

I have 2 functions, func1 and func2 whose job is to aggregate data from other input files, load them into data frames(df1, df2) separately and write to a single csv file. I am trying to get df1 and df2 to load different columns in the same csv file. Is this possible?

Sample Data:

Output.CSV:

```
Name  Age Sex Salary Deductions
Mike   50  M   50000  0
Molly  61  F   65000  500
Jake   22  M   28000  0
```

df1 loads Name Age and Sex columns. I want df2 to load the Salary and Deductions columns. 
In a nut shell, I basically am looking at an update(in RDBMS jargon) option where once df1 has loaded the first 3 columns, df2 should be able to update the other 2.

I'll appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks.

Comment: df1 and df2 have a column in common that you can use to link the data, or you just know that the data are and will always be perfectly aligned?

Comment: It'll be perfectly aligned. both df1 and df2 will run once a day and obtain only 1 row each. Nothing in common though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cbind` `df1` and `df2` before `write.csv`:

```
write.csv(cbind(df1,df2),"your csv path")
```

Comment: @vck- I considered this option before but it's not ideal for my use case. Ideally what I am expecting is more of an update option, where once df1 has loaded the first 3 columns, df2 should be able to update the other 2. I probably ought to modify the question a bit.

Comment: @mongofresher you can aslo read first 3 colmuns and `cbind` last two colmuns.

Comment: @vck- Since I see no other solutions, I guess I have to settle for the cbind option. Thanks for your time!